# How to access geolocation information in a Teams bot

Tags: geolocation, gps, botframework, microsoft-teams

Geolocation is listed as a device permission option, but none of the examples in the bot framework repository on GitHub explain how to use it. I also can’t find information in the documentation. Am I missing it? I don’t understand why the permission exists if it can’t be used, so I’m not sure what to do.

I’ve inspected the incoming data from POST requests to see if latitude and longitude are included. No geolocation/location/GPS data is visible even though the manifest includes geolocation in the devicePermission list.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the docs or sample you are referring to?

Comment: In short, I do not know how to send geolocation data to my back-end service. My use case is to get location data from my employees because my vendors require it. Instead of using a separate app, I'd like to incorporate the functionality into Teams. However, I can't figure out how to get the latitude and longitude values. Ultimately, all I need is for the values to show up in the POST request to my bot. The only example I've seen (in Subba's answer) is too complex to follow.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported to use with bot framework. You can access location using tab or task module. See the following note in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/location-capability): You can use Microsoft Teams JavaScript client SDK, which provides the tools necessary for your app to access the user’s native device capabilities.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. The link shows location data being used in a personal chat, which is not a tab. Are you saying this is possible with adaptive cards in a personal chat? It isn't clear what a task is; is that what you're referencing? In other words, is it possible to get the user's location in a personal chat?

Comment: My use case is to get the latitude and longitude from my employees so I can effectively upload the data to the vendor's database. I don't need to display anything in Teams for my workflow.

Comment: In short, It's not possible to get the user's location in a personal chat.

Comment: Messaging extensions can do it, right? I think those work in personal chats.